# How can I set up leiningen to work with multiple projects?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have multiple, separate leiningen projects that ostensibly could depend on one-another.

Example:

```
~/projects/mywebapp  (my own project)
~/projects/noir      (a clone of the github repo)
~/projects/clojureql (a clone of the github repo)
```

I want to have them all compiled into the same JVM at the same time. I would like to run the git repos bleeding edge (pulling new commits/making my own commits) and not have to run lein jar or lein deps and certainly not have to restart the VM if I change any of the projects.

Here's a use case:

After running lein swank, from within emacs, I connect to the repl and compile a file from mywebapp (with C-c-k), which requires a file from noir. It finds the version of the file in my projects directory. Later, I open that file, edit it, and compile it (with C-c-k).

Note that I'm not asking for auto-compiling when I do git pull. I just don't want to have to restart the JVM or do lengthy jar compiling processes.

Is this possible in leiningen? How can I set this up?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Does this question from the [Lein FAQ](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/FAQ.md#readme) help?

> **Q**: I want to hack two projects in parallel, but it's annoying to switch between them.
>
> **A**: Use a feature called checkout dependencies. If you create a directory called checkouts in your project root and symlink some other
>   project roots into it, Leiningen will allow you to hack on them in
>   parallel. That means changes in the dependency will be visible in the
>   main project without having to go through the whole
>   install/switch-projects/deps/restart-repl cycle. Note that this is not
>   a replacement for listing the project in :dependencies; it simply
>   supplements that for tighter change cycles.

Comment: Thanks! I must have missed it in the FAQ.

Comment: Very useful. That info should really be in the main documentation.

Answer (score 4):

If you're already using swank, you don't need lein checkout dependencies. You can just C-c C-k your project (which will load the jarred versions of noir/whatever), and then browse to your local version of noir and C-c C-k that as well. Swank happily sends all the code to your repl, and the jvm never need know that it came from a different place!

I can only recommend this for smallish changes though, because I think if you compile noir.core, which depends on (say) noir.internal, clojure will load the jarred version of noir.internal even while you compile the local version of noir.core. Even so, it's a handy trick in general.