# Working on a multiple leiningen project

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojurescript

I'm building a web apps that uses http-kit and clojurescript. At some point, I want to separate the front and back each into a lein project on its own. The scenario is:

1. For the front, if on development mode, uses a `lein ring server` to serve directory and the app will display a mock data.
2. The back will serve any `resources/public` in the front lein project.

I'm thinking of doing a nested lein project, but not sure how to handle it. Any suggestion or pointer is very much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set up leiningen to work with multiple projects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335709/how-can-i-set-up-leiningen-to-work-with-multiple-projects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your question is posted it is not very clear "*why* two projects?". It seems that you may be confusing different projects with different **profiles**, e.g. .. classpaths?

In order to work with multiple lein projects at once, similar to the way you would work with master pom => child poms with maven, there is a [lein-sub](https://github.com/kumarshantanu/lein-sub).

But in your case, it seems that what you want is different **lein profiles**, classpaths. Take a look at [lein profiles](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) documentation, it should solve "in dev do this, in test do this, in production do this" behavior you are after.